# Tesseract OCR large number of files

Tags: parallel-processing, tesseract

I have around 135000 `.TIF` files (1.2KB to 1.4KB) sitting on my hard drive. I need to extract text out of those files. If I run `tesseract` as a cron job I am getting 500 to 600 per hour at the most. Can anyone suggest me strategies so I can get atleast 500 per minute?

UPDATE:

Below is my code after implementing on suggestions given by @Mark still I dont seem to go beyond 20 files per min.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /mnt/ramdisk/input

function tess() 
{
    if [ -f /mnt/ramdisk/output/$2.txt ]
        then
        echo skipping $2
        return
    fi
    tesseract --tessdata-dir /mnt/ramdisk/tessdata -l eng+kan $1 /mnt/ramdisk/output/$2 > /dev/null 2>&1
}

export -f tess

find . -name \*.tif -print0 | parallel -0 -j100 --progress tess {/} {/.}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need **GNU Parallel**. Here I process 500 TIF files of 3kB each in 37s on an iMac. By way of comparison, the same processing takes 160s if done in a sequential `for` loop.

The basic command looks like this:

```
parallel --bar 'tesseract {} {.} > /dev/null 2>&1' ::: *.tif
```

which will show a progress bar and use all available cores on your machine. Here it is in action:

[image]

If you want to see what it would do without actually doing anything, use `parallel --dry-run`.

---

As you have 135,000 files it will probably overflow your command line length - you can check with `sysctl` like this:

```
sysctl -a kern.argmax
kern.argmax: 262144
```

So you need to pump the filenames into **GNU Parallel** on its `stdin` and separate them with null characters so you don't get problems with spaces:

```
find . -iname \*.tif -print0 | parallel -0 --bar 'tesseract {} {.} > /dev/null 2>&1'
```

---

If you are dealing with very large numbers of files, you probably need to consider the possibility of being interrupted and restarted. You could either `mv` each `TIF` file after processing to a subdirectory called `processed` so that it won't get done again on restarting, or you could test for the existence of the corresponding `txt` file before processing any `TIF` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
   if [ -f "${2}.txt" ]; then
      echo Skipping $1...
      return
   fi
   tesseract "$1" "$2" > /dev/null 2>&1
}

export -f doit
time parallel --bar doit {} {.} ::: *.tif
```

If you run that twice in a row, you will see it is near instantaneous the second time because all the processing was done the first time.

---

If you have millions of files, you could consider using multiple machines in parallel, so just make sure you have `ssh` logins to each of the machines on your network and then run across 4 machines, including the localhost like this:

```
parallel -S :,remote1,remote2,remote3 ...
```

where `:` is shorthand for the machine on which you are running.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I had tried `parallel` earlier but may be I was doing it wrong. I did what you suggested and I am getting around 50-60 per minute. I am using 4 CPU, 16 GB RAM Ubuntu 16.04 cloud vm. Any suggestions to further enhance performance will be highly appreciated. I need to process around 20 millions such `TIF`s after this sample of 135000.

Comment: I have added some more ideas at the bottom of my original answer. You could also try `-j 12` or `-j 24` to run 12 or 24 jobs at once and see if that helps...

Comment: How come you are able to do 500 in less than a minute, is it only due to difference in muscle power of our machines? I will consider adding more VM instances.

Comment: Maybe your machine has slow disks? You could try copying some of your TIFs to a RAMdrive and running again... `mkdir -p /media/RAMDRIVE; mount -t tmpfs -o size=2048M tmpfs /media/RAMDRIVE`

Comment: Cool ideas. I was also looking at `Spark` and `Hbase`. whats your opinion about that?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with `Spark` or `Hbase`.

Comment: @Naveed Have you considered to use a SSD to store the TIF files (~200MB, 135 files * 1.4KB) to reduce the disk access time? And try to use Python, or other supported language binding, to parallelize the tesseract tasks?

Comment: @thewaywewere Well at the time of signing up my cloud provider said its going to be SSD but I got a HDD. Not tried python in this case, can you tell more specifically how to use python for parallel processing?

Comment: @Naveed 1) SSD can provide access through up to 500MB/s or more with SATA3. 2) Use `multiprocessing` for `Python` to process multiple TIF files in parallel each time, depends on no. of CPU cores available.  Calling to `tesseract` task could be going to use 'pytesseract' or  use `subprocess' to shell and run tesseract command line at background.

Comment: @Naveed By the way, could you add a sample TIF image to the question? This might help if anyone interested to test and try before posting an answer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I mounted a RAM disk and getting about 350 per minute. If we want to run on multiple machines should  those machines too have GNU parallel installed?

Comment: I don’t believe it’s necessary, but it’s actually only a single Perl script so it’s easily installed and an essential part of any high performance toolbox!

Comment: @MarkSetchell I had to do certain iterations and eventually I have lost the performance of 350 per min even on RAM disk. I am posting my code in the original question. Please review and let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have various `-j` values ranging from 8 to 200, but that doesnt seem to affect performance at all. But I was getting 300-350 per min yesterday with `-j 200`, I dont know why it has stopped.

Comment: @MarkSetchell when I `cd` into `ramdisk` and run the program, after a while hit `ctrl+c`, then when I run the bash script again, the jobs seem to be hitting some bottleneck and I am getting blank `txt` files.

Comment: I'm not ignoring you, I just don't know the answers to your questions. Sorry.