# Bash subshell to file

Tags: bash, shell, subshell

I'm looping over a large file, on each line I'm running some commands, when they finish I want the entire output to be appended to a file.

Since there's nothing stopping me from running multiple commands at once, I tried to run this in the background `&`.

It doesn't work as expected, it just appends the commands to the file as they finish, but not in the order they appear in the subshell

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
  (
    echo -e "$line\n-----------------"
    trivy image --severity CRITICAL $line
    # or any other command that might take 1-2 seconds
    echo "============="
  ) >> vulnerabilities.txt &
done <images.txt
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: there's no guarantee jobs will complete in the same order in which they were started; in turn there's no guarantee on the order of data written to the (single) output file; if you want the outputs ordered you'll need to code for that (eg, have each background job write to a separate log file and then have the main script `wait` until all background jobs complete and then consolidate the various output files into a single output file in the desired order; another option, if the outputs can be prefixed with a background job number would be to `sort` the (single) output file afterwards)

Comment: All the background processes are running concurrently, and they're all writing to the file as they go. So all the output gets mixed together.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using **GNU Parallel** to get lots of things done in parallel. In your case:

```
parallel -k -a images.txt trivy image --severity CRITICAL > vulnerabilities.txt
```

The `-k` keeps the output in order. Add `--bar` or `--eta` for progress reports. Add `--dry-run` to see what it *would* do without *actually* doing anything. Add `-j ...` to control the number of parallel jobs at any one time - by default, it will run one job per CPU core at a time - so it will basically keep all your cores busy till the jobs are done.

If you want to do more processing on each line, you can declare a bash function and call that with each line as its parameter... see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60467834/2836621).